# How to display recursive folders in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am sending a JSON from my backend to my Angular application. I have a recursive folder structure that I need to display on my UI. I need to be able to enter each folder and browse just how the directory system on our OS works. I'm a newbie to Angular so I'm not sure how the routing can be implemented. Any advice is appreciated, or if you could suggest me a tutorial which has a similar structure, I searched but no luck so far. Thank you.

```
{
  id: "0",
  name: null,
  parentId: null,
  folderType: "chatMessages",
  folders: [
    {
      id: 3195588631115178,
      name: "Testfolder",
      parentId: null,
      folderType: "chatMessages",
      folders: [
        {
          id: "3195588620182363",
          name: "Subfolder",
          parentId: "3195588631115178",
          folderType: "chatMessages",
          folders: [
            {
              id: "3206824598737435",
              name: "Interesting",
              parentId: "3195588620182363",
              folderType: "chat",
              folders: [],
              items: [
                {
                  id: "3208409930553392",
                  name: "Message",
                  folderId: "3206824598737435",
                  updated: "2022-05-27T07:28:40.450Z",
                  frontendFolderId: null,
                  text: "<p>This is an HTML with Image.</p>",
                  keywords: "test",
                  subject: "What kind of subject",
                  slashCommand: "test",
                  language: "en-US",
                  setupItemId: "3208409930553392",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          items: [
            {
              id: "3195595211854821",
              name: "Message in subfolder",
              folderId: "3195588620182363",
              updated: "2022-05-19T12:05:39.503Z",
              frontendFolderId: null,
              text: "Message in subfolder",
              keywords: "test",
              subject: "Message in subfolder",
              slashCommand: "sub",
              language: "bn-BD",
              setupItemId: "3195595211854821",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      items: [],
    },
  ],
  items: [
    {
      id: "2888102250465731",
      name: "bye",
      folderId: null,
      updated: "2022-05-25T11:15:36.367Z",
      frontendFolderId: null,
      text: "Thanks for contacting us.  Please do not hesitate to contact us again if we can be of further assistance.",
      keywords: "bye",
      subject: null,
      slashCommand: null,
      language: null,
      setupItemId: "2888102250465731",
    },
  ],
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although not a comprehensive answer to your question, I would suggest you look into **[Angular Route Parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#route-parameters)**.

What I imagine is 2 types of routes based on the types of folders you have:

1. Chat Messages.
2. Chat.

Each can be given a distinct route with the ID as a parameter. Upon navigating to that route, you then request the information related to it ([by subscribing to the route parameters in your component](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service)), which should give you the children folders and any other information you want.

I highly recommend going through the Tour of Heroes guide that Angular provides especially since you mentioned you are new to Angular. It definitely helped me jump-start with the framework.

I hope this helps.